Задача из Яндекс Контест. Python
Ограничение времени 2 секунды
Ограничение памяти  256Mb
Ввод    casting.in
Вывод   casting.out

В театре работает n актеров. Известно, что среди них a – высоких, b – голубоглазых и с – блондинов. Для главной роли в новом спектакле режиссеру требуется только один высокий голубоглазый блондин. Чтобы спланировать свое время для беседы с каждым таким артистом из труппы театра, режиссеру необходимо узнать, какое максимальное или какое минимальное количество артистов из работающих в театре подходит для этой роли.
Требуется написать программу, которая по заданным числам n, a, b и с определяет минимальное или максимальное количество актеров, с которыми режиссер должен переговорить.
Формат ввода
Первая строка входного файла содержит одно число, которое задает, минимальное или максимальное количество актеров необходимо найти в данном тесте. Это число может принимать следующие значения:
1, если в данном теcте требуется определить минимальное количество актеров;
2, если в данном тесте требуется определить максимальное количество актеров.
Вторая строка входного файла содержит разделенные пробелами четыре целых числа: n, a, b, с (1 ≤ n ≤ 10 000, 0 ≤ a ≤ n, 0 ≤ b ≤ n, 0 ≤ c ≤ n).
Формат вывода
Выходной файл должен содержать одно число – минимальное или максимальное (в зависимости от входных данных) количество актеров, которые могут претендовать на главную роль в новом спектакле
Примечания
В первом примере, поскольку высоких актеров всего трое, то на главную роль не может подойти больше трех человек.
Во втором примере все актеры – блондины и все, кроме одного, – голубоглазые. Тогда среди трех высоких актеров найдутся хотя бы два голубоглазых (и, естественно, они будут блондинами). Следовательно, минимум два актера точно подойдут на главную роль в новом спектакле.
Система оценивания:
Правильные решения для тестов, в которых требуется найти минимальное количество актеров, будут оцениваться из 50 баллов.
Правильные решения для тестов, в которых требуется найти максимальное количество актеров, будут оцениваться из 50 баллов.
Несмотря на выделение отдельных групп тестов для минимального и максимального количества артистов, на окончательную проверку будут приниматься только решения, правильно работающие для всех тестов из условия задачи.
def input_func():
    x = int(input())
    n, a, b, c = input().split()
    n = int(float(n))
    a = int(float(a))
    b = int(float(b))
    c = int(float(c))

    return recursion_func(x, n, a, b, c)

def recursion_func(x, n, a, b, c):
    max_n = 10000
    if n < 0 or n > max_n:
        return input_func()

    e = [a, b, c]
    for i in e:
        if n < i or i < 0:
            return input_func()

    return func(x, n, a, b, c)


def func(x, n, a, b, c):
    if x == 2:
        return print(min(a, b, c))
    else:
        max_per = max(0, a, b, c)
        d = (a + b + c) - max_per - n

        if d >= 0:
            return print(d)
        else:
            return print(0)

input_func()

Мой код при проверке выдаёт ошибку, почему?

О чём по-вашему тут написано: "Ввод casting.in Вывод casting.out", "Первая строка входного файла", "Выходной файл  должен содержать одно число"?

выше в описание указанно как это необходимо понимать (строка ввода и строка вывода)

Слово "файл" вам о чём-то говорит? "casting.in" и "casting.out" - это что, по-вашему? Ну либо я чего-то не понимаю в этой системе. Хотя, судя по тому, как у вас код написан, скорее всего всё-таки вы чего-то не понимаете.

Вы вводите данные с консоли. И выводите на неё же. А в задании написано брать данные из файла casting.in и выводить результат в файл casting.out. Ну и обратите внимание на код вида return print(d), это лажа какая-то. Этот return напечатает значение переменной d и вернёт None, это ли в нём задумывалось? Так код обычно не пишут.

casting.in - это поле ввода кода или загруженный файл.py

casting.out - это поля вывода результата, мне почему так кажется

https://contest.yandex.ru/roiarchive/contest/2008/problems/?success=121097654#2537/2014_01_30/xhkIZHawoD

отправил ссылку на задачу

понял, буду дальше разбираться

спасибо вам за информацию

Мой код при проверке выдаёт ошибку, почему? Наверное, потому что алгоритм неправильный... вы его, кстати, вообще не потрудились описАть - почему? правда думаете, что мы сами станем догадываться, что делает ваш код и с какой собственно радости? тем более что задача элементарно решается аналитически...

Вы можете улучшить вопрос, если озвучите конкретную ошибку/проблему. Фразы "Мой код при проверке выдаёт ошибку, почему?" будет не достаточно

Про формат данных говорить не буду. А протестировать могу:
Для x = 1, n = 3, a = b = c = 2 программа возвращает единицу. Но вот трое артистов:

высокий голубоглазый,

голубоглазый блондин,

блондин и высокий.


Среди них нет ни одного подходящего, а программа утверждает что один должен быть. Ошибка.
